# Routing inside expo without routing labels

Tags: reactjs, expo

I am new in expo developing.

The standard routing, that provide expo, concern me, that it is provide from hood - labels and tabs, for instance:

```
const App = () => (
  <NavigationContainer>
    <Stack.Navigator>
      <Stack.Screen name="Home" component={HomeScreen} />
      <Stack.Screen name="Details" component={DetailsScreen} />
      <Stack.Screen name="Settting" component={SettingScreen} />
    </Stack.Navigator>
  </NavigationContainer>
);
```

I wonder if I can route between multiple pages bypassing NavigationContainer and can route between pages to pass 'id' of my page what I desire to navigate (some pseudo code):

```
export default function SettingScreen() {
  return (
    <View>
      <Link href="/Home">Home page</Link>
    </View>
  );
}
```

Can I use expo approach to do routing between pages bypassing standard navigation label or hide it?

Thanks in advance

Comment: I think I am figure out that, if it is not necessary to have hierarchy links tree in app, I can use modal window instead of route through different links